# Proof indipendency AX BX multinormal distribution when AB'=0

Tags: variance, independence, covariance-matrix

my issue is this: I'm trying to find the proof for a famous therorem I've been told during a lecture at the university.
This are our guest stars:

1. $X_n \sim N(0,1)$ is a vector of iid random variables;
2. $A,B$ are two $mxn$ matrix
3. $ AB'=0$

We want to proof that $AX$ and $BX$ are two indipendent normal vector.
We know that in case of normal (in this case multinormal) uncorrelation implies indipendency. So I'm gonna check the uncorrelation assumption, if it's true then they're indipendent. That's how I would do:
$$Cov(AX,BX)= ACov(X,X)B'=AI_nB'=AB'=0$$They're uncorellated so they are indipendent.

But during my class the proof has been done in an another way that I'm finding hard to get:
we choosed to build a new vector, that's: $(AX,BX)$ and we checked this the expected value of $\mathbb{E}=\left[ \begin{pmatrix} AX\\BX \end{pmatrix} \begin{matrix}(AX, BX)'\end{matrix} \right]$ so we get:
$\mathbb{E}=\begin{bmatrix} AXX'A' & AXX'B' \\BXX'A' & BXX'B' \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} A\mathbb{E}[XX']A' & A\mathbb{E}[XX']B' \\B\mathbb{E}[XX']A' & B\mathbb{E}[XX']B' \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} AA' & AB' \\BA' & BB' \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} AA' & 0 \\0 & BB' \end{bmatrix}$.

My questions is:

1. Is the secondy way correct? And what does that mean? That where we have zero's we have the variance covariance matrix of AX and BX and AA' and BB' are the variance covarince matrices of the two of the picked alone?
   I'm quite in difficult why we had behaved in this way. 
   Are the two ways saying the same thing?
   Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes it is correct. $E[XX’]$ is the covariance matrix of $X$. You have already prove this part as 0 ( the first prove).

Comment: And is the second one correct?

Comment: I mean why decided to use a new vector (AX,BX) does it have a meaning?